# google map - user choses not to allow location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am faced with a situation where the user does not want to allow the system to use the google location api to center the map on them.

**I need to set a default value if the user opts out of using the location. Is there a way to accomplish this?**

Comment: does that mean that you need to get at least which city is he in (coarse location) if he opts out of exact geo location checking?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961226/event-that-fires-if-the-user-does-not-allow-using-the-location (by the same asker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is! Google maps uses navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() method to get your current location. This method allows a success callback (when a user says yes) and error callback (when user says no). It is also good to check if the browser supports geolocation. The following shows how to use it

```
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(hasGeolocation, noGeolocation)
        } else {
            geolocationNotSupported();
        }

        function hasGeolocation() {
            console.log("yeah!")
        }

        function noGeolocation() {
            console.log("user said no!")
        }

        function geolocationNotSupported() {
            console.log("this browser does not support geolocation")
        }
```

There is also an example on google maps api docs to show this in context of google maps usage
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation

Comment: nice - thank you....   i set the alert to display when they answer no....  but the alert does not display...

Answer (score 0):

when you are initializing your map you are defining [map options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions). Just define the 'center' option in this moment.